# Use accelerometer

Tags: iphone, xcode

How to rotate the `UIImageView` on z-axis with using accelerometer in iPhone device. Please help me out with any source code.

Answer (score 0):

The z-direction points towards you, so to say. Try accessing the layer of the view. It should have a z-parameter.

here is the accelerometer example code ...

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/44799/1954

There is also SO post

[How can I rotate an image in response to the iPhone's accelerometer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954711/how-can-i-rotate-an-image-in-response-to-the-iphones-accelerometer)