# accelerometer speedometer+iphone application

Tags: iphone

I want to implement accelerometer speedometer like functionality in iPhone application. Is there any good tutorial that will explain me in detail about how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the below  SO post

[Use accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500924/use-accelerometer)

Here is the Sample project

```
AccelerometerGraph
BubbleLevel
GLGravity
oalTouch
```

Check below link

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html